# New Zero-day exploit reportedly found affecting Linux/Android (CVE-2016-0728)

Tags: kernel, security

[Russia Today reports (20 January 2016)](https://www.rt.com/usa/329512-linux-security-flaw-millions-risk/) that there is a new zero-day exploit that has been discovered affecting Linux and all Linux-based OSes for computers and phones.

What is the deal; how does it affect Ubuntu; and when can we expect security updates that will close this security hole?

Comment: *When* ? as soon as possible, cannot give you specific date or time

Comment: which kernel is vulnerable and what mitigation to address the vulnerability?

Comment: More details here: http://www.networkworld.com/article/3023447/security/linux-zero-day-affects-most-androids-millions-of-linux-pcs.html AND http://perception-point.io/2016/01/14/analysis-and-exploitation-of-a-linux-kernel-vulnerability-cve-2016-0728/

Answer (score 35):

[It has been patched already](http://linux.softpedia.com/blog/canonical-patches-the-zero-day-linux-kernel-vulnerability-in-all-supported-ubuntu-oses-499134.shtml).

Quoting the article:

> [...] "Yevgeny Pats discovered that the session keyring implementation in the Linux kernel did not properly reference count when joining an existing session keyring. A local attacker could use this to cause a denial of service (system crash) or possibly execute arbitrary code with administrative privileges," reads today's [Ubuntu Security Notice USN-2872-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2872-1/) for Ubuntu 15.10. [...]

and

> [...] patches are now available for the Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf), Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet), and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) distributions. [...]

and

> [...] you are urged to upgrade the kernel packages to `linux-image-4.2.0-25 (4.2.0-25.30)` for Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf), `linux-image-4.2.0-1020-raspi2 4.2.0-1020.27` for Ubuntu 15.10 (Raspberry Pi 2), `linux-image-3.19.0-47 (3.19.0-47.53)` for Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet), and `linux-image-3.13.0-76 (3.13.0-76.120)` for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr). [...]

So users of the patched releases (15.10 / 15.04 / 14.04, and [according to Canonical also 12.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2870-2/)) may (and should) upgrade right away by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and rebooting the computer afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  We will pass along the info ASAP!

Comment: @IWPCHI If you found this answer useful remember that [you may accept it as well](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @IWPCHI Don't thank Kos!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Answer (score 16):

Just complementing @kos's nice answer:

The Zero day exploit (CVE-2016-0728) [was found by the researchers at Perception Point](http://perception-point.io/2016/01/14/analysis-and-exploitation-of-a-linux-kernel-vulnerability-cve-2016-0728/).

It was introduced in 3.8 Vanilla Kernel. So the Ubuntu releases using kernel versions 3.8 or later are vulnerable. As @kos already mentioned, on a supported release you can just upgrade the kernel to install the patch:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**How to Check the Vulenerability (taken from [here](http://perception-point.io/2016/01/14/analysis-and-exploitation-of-a-linux-kernel-vulnerability-cve-2016-0728/)):**

Install `libkeyutils-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libkeyutils-dev
```

Copy this [C program from github](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/PerceptionPointTeam/18b1e86d1c0f8531ff8f/raw/5a90e6f98de85f35708087620de73bed3bf16880/cve_2016_0728.c), written by the Perception Point team to test the exploit.

Save the codes in a file e.g. `test_2016_0728.c` and compile:

```
gcc test_2016_0728.c -o test_2016_0728 -lkeyutils -Wall
```

Run the compiled program as **normal user**:

```
./test_2016_0728 -PP1
```

It would take some time, if your kernel is vulnerable after the completion of the program you will see that your privilege has been escalated i.e. you have become **`root`**.

Comment: Too bad I had upgraded already or I definetly would have tested this!

Comment: @kos ummm...bad for you :P

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce the exploit? I didn't find anyone who did so far.

Comment: @Jakuje I upgraded my kernel before I came to read the perception point's article.. According to the article it is the way..

Comment: @Jakuje I'm testing the exploit on my Pi right now, which is running an unpatched version of Raspbian Jessie. It's running, but not much seems to be happening.

Comment: @HeatherBrown It would take time as it involves incrementing the 32 bit reference counter for keyring facility to 2^32..it would take about 30 minutes for a i7 machine..

Comment: I may have copied sobering wrong. I let it run for 27 hours on the pi 2 without getting past the "increfing" step. Unless that's the expected result for a patched system

Comment: @HeatherBrown "Increfing" is the first step where the counter is being exhausted by 2^32 values sequentially.. A pi is the worst thing you could test this on..you need to use a powerful machine, like i said a core i7 would need around 30 minutes or so..